# Identifier: what happens when I do id(36.8)

Tags: python, variables

From what I understood, for all integers between -5 and 256, python associates unique identifier to them.

I would like to understand better the identifier scheme works.

Consider the following:

```
id(36.8) # returns 2043124617296
```

Python cannot have already allocated memory for all possible float existing. So when I wrote this line did it actually **created** the memory slot for this float 36.8 ?

I also noticed that if I do:

```
ccc=36.8
id(ccc) # returns something different than id(36.8)
```

Thus in practice, for all integers outside than -5 and 256, python will create a new memory slot each time I create a variable ? And even if many times the same value (ie 36.8 here) is being used, it will be associated to different memory slots ?

[edit]: I am confused for this last point. I re-ran the script:

```
id(36.8) # returns an ID
ccc=36.8
id(ccc) # returns the SAME ID
```

and it actually returns the same id now. So what is there to understand ?
Is it that the values between -5 and 256 will always have the same ID whenever the script is being run.

Values outside of this range will have different id each time the script is being ran in principle (new console). **BUT** if I associated different variables to the same number their id will be identical ?
For instance, with ANY_NUMBER a number (not a variable), thus something like 86.454 for instance.

```
a=ANY_NUMBER
b=ANY_NUMBER
```

id(a), id(b) id(ANY_NUMBER) will be the same **always**

Comment: Yes. That's what it does.

Comment: 1) The caching of the integers from -5 to 256 is an implementation detail. I've heard that newer C-Python versions do cache even more. (you may have to check the python source to see what's going on behind the curtains) 2) There's no guarantee that every time the same int/float value is used, it will have its own new memory adress. Again, as an implementation detail, Python might decide to cache it or to use an existing value. After all, ints and floats are immutable, so there's no danger in having multiple variable names point to the same value in memory. The same applies to other immutables.

Comment: @mkrieger1 actually I am confused. I did another test with: id(89.3), followed by e=89.3, and print(id(e)) and this times it returned me the *same* memory value. Why so ? Was 36.8 a specific value ?? I am confused now.

Comment: @MikeScotty I edited. I think my question is more basic. It is fine if what happens between -5 and 256 is a detail. But I want to understand the general picture of ID. Thus I edited for that. Thanks.

Comment: There is absolutely *no* guarantee in the language about basically anything you are asking. This is very implementation specific, doubly so for values that are potentially owned exclusively by the interpreted making the idea of "object lifetime" void. For example, PyPy will not return the memory address of floats but a consistent, unique id based on the float value. Even for CPython, you might see different behaviour in the REPL versus modules due to interning and caching.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see. thanks.